# Pandas DF replace value in array with column using dictionary mapping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with column containing array of values as per below

| name | urls |
| --- | --- |
| bob | [https:/1, https:/2] |
| mary | [https:/1, https:/3] |

I would like to map the values within the array in column "urls" to a dictionary and replace the values to those from the dictionary. Example dictionary below

```
mapping_dictionary = {'https:/1': 'google',
 'https:/2': 'yahoo',
 'https:/3': 'bing'}
```

So end result would look something like this:

| name | urls |
| --- | --- |
| bob | [google, yahoo] |
| mary | [google, bing] |

Is it possible to do this using pandas.replace or pandas mapping?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode` "urls" columns, `map` "mapping_dictionary", aggregate by the index to lists:

```
df['urls'] = df['urls'].explode().map(mapping_dictionary).fillna("").groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
   name             urls
0   bob  [google, yahoo]
1  mary   [google, bing]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try

```
df['value' = df.urls.map(lambda x : [*map(mapping_dictionary.get, x)])
0    [google, yahoo]
1     [google, bing]
Name: urls, dtype: object
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the urls using `apply` and `lambda`, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['bob', 'mary'],
    'urls': [['https:/1', 'https:/2'], ['https:/1', 'https:/3']]
})

m_dict = {
    'https:/1': 'google',
    'https:/2': 'yahoo',
    'https:/3': 'bing'
}


df['urls'] = df['urls'].apply(lambda urls: [m_dict[url] for url in urls])

print(df)
#   name             urls
#0   bob  [google, yahoo]
#1  mary   [google, bing]
```